# What is the difference between defining variables using def and without?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In relation to Jenkins DSL, what is the difference between:

```
def cwd = pwd()
```

and

```
cwd = pwd()
```

?

Comment: `def` is a local variable.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's a difference of scope. When you assign a value to a variable without a "def" or other type, in a Groovy script, it's added to the "binding", the global variables for the script. That means it can be accessed from all functions within the script. It's a lot like if you had the variable defined at the top of the script.

You could wind up with unexpected behavior if multiple threads are acting on the script.

```
def a = {
  x = 1
  println x
}
def b = {
  x = 2
  println x
}
new Thread(a).start()
new Thread(b).start()
```

... could produce two ones, two twos, or a mix.

In contrast, using "def" makes a local variable:

```
def a = {
  def x = 1
  println x
}
def b = {
  def x = 2
  println x
}
new Thread(a).start()
new Thread(b).start()
```

... will always print a 1 and a 2, in arbitrary order.

Answer (score 7):

It's a good question, but it's more a Groovy question.

From what I understand, defining a variable without `def` keyword will work from a script, but not if you were in a class method. Example from this [blog post](http://blog.cacoethes.co.uk/groovyandgrails/a-couple-of-notes-about-groovy-syntax) :

```
class MyTest {
    def testMethod() {
        y = 3
        println y
    }    
}

t = new MyTest()
t.testMethod()
```

Variable `t` will be defined without problem but `y` definition will throw an exception.

What it means is that in our context (Jenkins pipeline) you could always define your variable without the `def` keyword because you are always in a script context and your variables will be bound to the script. However, I think it is good practice to use `def` keyword because it shows you know when you instantiate your variables, and it also can avoid some problems of duplicate variables definitions (if you define them with the `def` keyword at least compilation will fail if you defined the same variable twice).

Finally, from [Groovy documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_def_and_type) :

> When using def in Groovy, the actual type holder is Object (so you can
>   assign any object to variables defined with def, and return any kind
>   of object if a method is declared returning def).

So you might want to be specific and specify the type of variable you are defining. In your case you could define `cwd` as :

```
String cwd = pwd()
```

It would forbid you to do things like :

```
def cwd = pwd()
cwd = 1000     // Valid code

String cwd2 = pwd()
cwd2 = 1000    // Will fail compilation
```