# "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: var1 for class: groovy.lang.Binding" when running a Jenkins groovy pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using Jenkins 2.346.3 and running a pipeline. In this pipeline i check if a variable(var1) contains a substring of var1. when executing this code block it throws "MissingPropertyException" error.

```
def var1 = "Image is up to date"
    
if( var1 =~ "Image"){
  echo "sub string matched"
}
```

This throws the following error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: var1 for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:266)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:375)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:379)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:355)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:355)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:355)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:56)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:73)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:158)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

But when i run it like bellow, it works just fine.

```
if( "Image is up to date" =~ "Image"){
  echo "sub string matched"
}
```

This gives the output as sub string matched.

I also tried with `var1.contains("Image")` . This also gives the above error.

I'm using declarative pipeline script and using groovy sandbox.

Any idea on how solve this? or a workaround this?

Comment: Try changing `def var1 = "Image is up to date"` to `var1 = "Image is up to date"`... Ie: remove the Def

Comment: **tim_yates's** suggestion worked for me. You saved me  from lot of troubles, thank you.

Comment: The reason could be found in here[](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514795/what-is-the-difference-between-defining-variables-using-def-and-without#:~:text=When%20you%20assign%20a%20value,the%20top%20of%20the%20script.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with declarative is that you can't use directly groovy code, you need to use `script` block to be able to perform such actions or write scripted pipeline.

```
script{
 def var1 = "Image is up to date"

 if( var1 =~ "Image"){
 echo "sub string matched"
 }
}
```

You should note that the `var1` variable won't be accessible anywhere else.

Comment: Above code was already inside of the `script` block. But it didn't work.